# Give byte existing byte value (homework)

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I need to make an assignment where I switch the values of a certain int. For example: `0xaabbccdd` should be turned in to `0xddccbbaa`.

I've already extraced all of the bytes from the given number and their values are correct.

```
unsigned int input;

scanf("%i", &input);

unsigned int first_byte = (input >> (8*0)) & 0xff;
unsigned int second_byte = (input >> (8*1)) & 0xff;
unsigned int third_byte = (input >> (8*2)) & 0xff;
unsigned int fourth_byte = (input >> (8*3)) & 0xff;
```

Now I'm trying to set an empty int variable (aka `00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000`) to those byte values, but turned around. So how can I say that the first byte of the empty variable is the fourth byte of the given input? I've been trying different combinations of bitwise operations, but I can't seem to wrap my head around it. I'm pretty sure I should be able to do something like:

```
answer *first byte* | fourth_byte;
```

I would appreciate any help, becau'se I've been stuck and searching for an answer for a couple of hours now.

Comment: You need to shift the bytes to the correct position in the integer before ORing.

Comment: But I can OR an entire byte if I'm on the correct position? Because I can't seem to do that correct. I'm not sure how I can OR an entire byte for the empty variable. I only found ways to do it per bit, plus everytime I try to edit the empty variable I end up assigning an int to it, which is ofcourse not what I want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your code :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    unsigned int input = 0xaabbccdd;
    unsigned int first_byte = (input >> (8*0)) & 0xff;
    unsigned int second_byte = (input >> (8*1)) & 0xff;
    unsigned int third_byte = (input >> (8*2)) & 0xff;
    unsigned int fourth_byte = (input >> (8*3)) & 0xff;

    printf(" 1st : %x\n 2nd : %x\n 3rd : %x\n 4th : %x\n", 
        first_byte, 
        second_byte, 
        third_byte, 
        fourth_byte);

    unsigned int combo = first_byte<<8 | second_byte;
    combo = combo << 8 | third_byte;
    combo = combo << 8 | fourth_byte;

    printf(" combo : %x ", combo);

    return 0;
}
```

It will output `0xddccbbaa`

Here's a more elegant function to do this :

```
unsigned int setByte(unsigned int input, unsigned char byte, unsigned int position)
{
    if(position > sizeof(unsigned int) - 1)
        return input;

    unsigned int orbyte = byte;
    input |= byte<<(position * 8);

    return input;
}
```

Usage :

```
unsigned int combo = 0;
    combo = setByte(combo, first_byte, 3);
    combo = setByte(combo, second_byte, 2);
    combo = setByte(combo, third_byte, 1);
    combo = setByte(combo, fourth_byte, 0);

    printf(" combo : %x ", combo);
```

Comment: Thanks! That actually makes a lot of sense, and it did the trick. Didn't you know you could do it that way.

Answer (score 1):

unsigned int result;

result = ((first_byte <<(8*3)) | (second_byte <<(8*2)) | (third_byte <<(8*1)) | (fourth_byte))

Answer (score 1):

You can extract the bytes and put them back in order as you're trying, that's a perfectly valid approach. But here are some other possibilities:

`bswap`, if you have access to it. It's an x86 instruction that does exactly this. It doesn't get any simpler. Similar instructions may exist on other platforms. Probably not good for a C assignment though.

Or, swapping adjacent "fields". If you have AABBCCDD and first swap adjacent 8-bit groups (get BBAADDCC), and then swap adjacent 16-bit groups, you get DDCCBBAA as desired. This can be implemented, for example: (not tested)

```
x = ((x & 0x00FF00FF) <<  8) | ((x >>  8) & 0x00FF00FF);
x = ((x & 0x0000FFFF) << 16) | ((x >> 16) & 0x0000FFFF);
```

Or, a closely related method but with rotates. In AABBCCDD, AA and CC are both rotated to the left by 8 positions, and BB and DD are both rotated right by 8 positions. So you get:

```
x = rol(x & 0xFF00FF00, 8) | ror(x & 0x00FF00FF, 8);
```

This requires rotates however, which most high level languages don't provide, and emulating them with two shifts and an OR negates their advantage.

Comment: Thanks, swapping the adjacent fields was another approach I was thinking about as well. But for extra clarity I used the "extract" method. These are good suggestions though, I'll definitely keep them in mind!

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    unsigned int input = 0xaabbccdd,
                 byte[4] = {0},
                 n = 0,
                 output = 0;
    do
    {
        byte[n] = (input >> (8*n)) & 0xff;
        n = n + 1;
    }while(n < 4);

    n = 0;
    do
    {
        printf(" %d : %x\n", byte[n]);
        n = n + 1;
    }while (n < 4);

    n = 0;
    do
    {
        output = output << 8 | byte[n];
        n = n + 1;
    }while (n < 4);

    printf(" output : %x ", output );

    return 0;
}
```

You should try to avoid repeating code.

Comment: Yeah I know. Just writing it down in such a way that I can understand it easily. And when I fully comprehend what everything is I go and refactor it. Cheers

Comment: Don t worry, I do that a lot too. Cheers.